# Remove element from firestore array

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to remove an element from the array currently stored in firestore.

I have checked everywhere even the firestore documentation and what they suggest is not working.
This is currently my code and so far it does nothing when trying to delete from listview.

```
         Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();
         note.put("posts", FieldValue.delete());
         documentReference.update("posts", FieldValue.arrayRemove(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()));
         usersEmotions.remove(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
         listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
         listAdapter.remove(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

My firebase structure - 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an item from an array, your client app needs to pass the entire object value of the item.  It won't work if you just pass an index or one of the nested values in that item.

For your data, that means you will need to build a HashMap with the exact contents of the item (both emotion number and text string), and pass that to update().  For example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(emotion, ...);
map.put(text, "...");
documentReference.update(posts, FieldValue.arrayRemove(map));
```

If you don't know the entire item's contents, this won't work.  Your only other options is to read the document, modify the list in memory, and write it modified list back to the document.